# VPN tunnel from client A through relay B to server C

Tags: linux, networking, vpn

I need to send traffic from a client machine, A, to a VPN server, C, but  *through a relay host, B*.  All three of them have public IPv4 addresses, but for policy reasons, A must not send traffic directly to C under any circumstances.  A is only allowed to talk to B.  The other hard requirement is for a "real" VPN, appearing as a network interface on A -- not a SOCKS proxy (which I know how to do with SSH).

I control the software on all three machines, and there *shouldn't* be any issue with NAT or firewalls.

I have not been able to figure out even *which VPN software* can do this, let alone how to set it up.  All documentation for both OpenVPN and Openswan discusses only direct connections from client to server.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to send traffic from a client machine, A, to a VPN server, C, but through a relay host, B.

You need to set up a tunnel between A and B, and point A's route to C into the tunnel. Alternatively, you set up tunnels between A and B, and between B and C and route between tunnels.

Product recommendations are explicitly off topic here, sorry. And SOCKS has nothing to do with SSH by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You could setup an HTTP proxy on server B and use OpenVPN.

https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#http

Comment: This will probably work for me if nothing better comes along, but I'd prefer something that doesn't require TCP-based tunneling; I've had bad luck with it for this application.

Answer (score 0):

ou can use softether vpn server at point C and B use cascade connection between them anable secureNAt on Point C, then make vpn connection from A to B all traffic will goes from cascade to C and your vpn clint public IP will be C.